# Pre-processor #define with argument, but no function body

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

So I am wondering what a `#define foo(bar)` does. It seems to have an argument, but no body. Let me give you some context:

### Definition

```
#ifndef __success
    #define __nvapi_success
    #define __success(epxr)
#endif
```

### Usage

```
#define NVAPI_INTERFACE extern __success(return == NVAPI_OK) NvAPI_Status __cdecl
```

In the end, NVAPI_INTERFACE is used for function declarations, like so:

```
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Initialize();
```

This is all taken from NVAPI, [Nvidia's Core SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi) that I am trying to figure out.

Comment: It's just defined empty, so the argument is ignored. They might define it differently on different platforms/in the future etc.

Comment: lethal-guitar thanks. So that means that I can remove the __success(...) part from the define?

Comment: Why would you want to modify a library header?

Comment: @Dennis Kuypers: Remove? Why? Because of that `#ifndef` the definition you quoted is a "default" definition, i.e. it is the one that takes place if and only if `__success` was not defined previously. Are you sure you have no other spots in the code where `__success` can be defined and defined differently (i.e. as something non-empty)?

Comment: I see a lot of macros that are defined like that. When using /P on the preprocessor it gives me preprocessed files where the `__success(..)` are left as-is. There seem to be no other #define directives for those "empty" defines that could take place. But I might as well be missing something

Comment: @AndreyT Looks like i was missing some includes. In the sample project they are using #include <windows.h> and a few more, now it works better.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I just ran into this issue with NVAPI, adding #include <Windows.h> resolved my "error C2059: syntax error : 'return'" issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro with "no body" (no replacement list) simply has *empty* body. This means that every "invocation" of that macro in the code will be replaced with an *empty* sequence of tokens, i.e. the references to that macro will simply disappear without any effect.

In your above example the authors of the code simply wanted all invocations of `__success(epxr)` to just disappear from the code under certain circumstances (i.e. if `__success` was not defined previously). That's all there is to it.

The same is true for `__nvapi_success` macro. I.e. whether your macro has arguments or not does not make any difference in this regard.

Under some other circumstances this macro might get defined differently, with non-empty replacement list. If you look through the rest of the source code you might discover other places that define `__success(epxr)` differently and conditions, under which it happens.

Comment: This answers my initial question, so thank you for that. I suspect that I am doing something wrong / I am missing some other files and that this may be the reason for the problems that turn up.